# Android application crashes, but doesn't restart - resumes from another point in the application

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports, acra

The application in question has already been deployed. I have found out about [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra), and will be adding that in to find out why the application crashes are happening.

My problem however, is that the application will crash (the dialog will show up giving you the option to either "Force Close" or "Wait"), but instead of restarting the application completely, it resumes from a point before the crash occurred. This causes problems however, that are only fixed by restarting the application (eg. sudden loss of data, crashes that don't make sense, etc.).

So how can I force my application, once crashed, to just end? (NOT restart).

Edit: The biggest issue is that after the application crashes, all the data in my preferences file disappears, until the app is restarted when it comes back.

Comment: I believe what you are facing here is an 'ANR' or Activity Not Responding, which is different from an app crash (Force Close). Some operation in your app seems to be blocking the main thread (the UI thread)for a certain period of time, which is prompting this force close/wait dialog. If you choose wait, the app would remain unresponsive for the extent of the completion of that operation. Then, the app would resume. But once you press 'Force Close', the app is going to shut down and restart when you access it the next time

Comment: It isn't the case of a ANR, sometimes it shows "Force Close" or "Wait" which is the UI thread being blocked, but sometimes it is just a "Force Close" so the application has actually crashed. And the app doesn't shut down consistently - on some platforms it does shut down, but on others it just resumes from a previous point and has lost all of the prefrences data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android will re-start the last active activity by default. Instead of forcing it to restart, the better strategy would be to fix your application, so that activities don't crash or exit gracefully even if no data is available. If you absolutely depend on some data (intent extras) and there are no defaults, you can just call `finish()` if it is not available, or start the main/parent activity.

Another way is to have your own default exception handler which re-starts the main activity, etc. after reporting the crash using ACRA (I believe there is a feature request for this in ACRA's bugtracker).

Comment: I would like to fix my application, but unfortunately it has already been deployed, and I've added ACRA to catch the exceptions now, but just in case anything happens I want to quit the application forcefully. I checked ACRA and couldn't find that feature ... I assume it hasn't been implemented yet?

Comment: Just because its deployed doesn't mean you cant fix it and redeploy it, people will gladly update their apps to fix crashes.

Comment: Depending on which OS version it is (or how it was implemented by the phone) it will close the application if the application crashes. I haven't been able to find a way to force close the application when it crashes, even with ACRA. The most you can do is a "quiet" crash with ACRA currently, so that no dialog shows up.

I've added the update with ACRA installed, so I will hopefully be able to get the reasons for the crashes and then I can fix them. I'm  just going to mark your question as correct because its the closest to being correct ... there isn't an answer though.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but for future references and googlers, here is a complete answer from another, hard to find, stackoverflow question: [Android App Restarts upon Crash/force close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560590/android-app-restarts-upon-crash-force-close)

---

create a class used to handle `unCaughtException`

```
public class MyExceptionHandler implements
        java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final Context myContext;
    private final Class<?> myActivityClass;

    public MyExceptionHandler(Context context, Class<?> c) {

        myContext = context;
        myActivityClass = c;
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {

        StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
        System.err.println(stackTrace);// You can use LogCat too
        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, myActivityClass);
        String s = stackTrace.toString();
        //you can use this String to know what caused the exception and in which Activity
        intent.putExtra("uncaughtException",
                "Exception is: " + stackTrace.toString());
        intent.putExtra("stacktrace", s);
        myContext.startActivity(intent);
        //for restarting the Activity
        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Then in every thread (usually you have just one, unless you start a new thread (Async or ... , ofcourse you know about threads if you are able to make new ;) ), set this class as the `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(this,
            YourCurrentActivity.class));
```

Remember though!
Do it in the very last step of developing your application, you HAVE to at least try handle all of your exceptions one by one before leaving them for `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`

Comment: we need both ACRA as well as restart the entire application

Comment: awesome solution