# How to Relaunch application when app gets force closed

Tags: android

I have a requirement to provide option to user to relaunch 
the application whenever application gets force closed without going to Home.

Can it be possible??

I want to make sure 
is it possible or not??

Actually its a client requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android App Restarts upon Crash/force close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560590/android-app-restarts-upon-crash-force-close)

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible.

In your application class call the set the following in `onCreate`.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(_unCaughtExceptionHandler);



    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler _unCaughtExceptionHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Your packagename");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);

    }
};
```

This method will catch all the uncaught exceptions thrown by your code and restart your app without any crash.

Comment: OP is not talking about a crash, but a forced close of the activity. Does the forced close raise an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible you need to follow below 2 steps only..

**Step 1 :- Create a class as `MyCrashHandler` as**

```
 public static class MyCrashHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            //Handle your crash here...Show dialog etc..
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Step 2 :- Now you need to register this crash handler in your activity,,As**

```
Thread.currentThread().setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyCrashHandler ());
```